# Read my non public posts on Google+

Tags: php, google-plus

I want to build a PHP script where I need to login for reading my own posts for a given circle.

I followed the instructions on the [quick start page](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php), so I'm authorized to read data and Google know who I am. There must be some API to read my own posts, please guide me to the right reference for implementing that by my own.

If this is not possible is it possible to find (my) posts by an given hash tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

[Google+ Docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)

There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=192) you can star to show Google your interest in such an API.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you should do some pre work;

1. Go to [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
2. Select Services
3. Enable Google+ API services.
4. Select API Access
5. Simple API Access > grab your API Key.

And you can do this with php like below;

```
<?php

$google_plus_id = '106670447018211124292';
$appKey = 'app_key_here';
$streams = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' . $google_plus_id . '/activities/public?key='. $appKey));

foreach ($streams->items as $item) {
  echo $item->title .
    date('F jS Y @ H:i:s',strtotime($item->published)) .
    $item->object->content .
    '<br />';
}
```

You can also test this code's job on google api console.

**1.)** Go to [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and select Google+ API

**2.)** Select **APIs** menu on left menu

**3.)** Click on **public.activities.list** on that page

[image]

**4.)** Enter your **profile id** in **userId** section and type "public" on **collection** section then click **Execute**. You can see below;

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in my question I did that preconditions already. However that code returns only my public posts not my private.

Comment: My code is already does what you said. You can also test on google api console. Se my updated answer